# What is a good Azure service to use if I want to look through a database of records to find the top 5 most similar records?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have a database of records in Cosmos DB. I want to write something that would allow me to, given a particular record (let's say it has a description), find the top 5 records with the most similar descriptions to that particular record. What would be the best Azure service to accomplish this?

I looked into text analytics, but it didn't seem to have the functionality I'd need. Maybe I'm wrong, open to any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried anything? If tried, could you please share it to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

It could be worth looking into Power BI. I've never worked with Cosmos DB but the Microsoft documentation should help you get started https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/powerbi-visualize

Answer (score 0):

1. Using azure cognitive search service, you can retrieve top 5 records having similar description or containing a specific word.
2. I have a table in cosmos DB with data as shown below,
   [image]

```
[
  {
     "id": "1",
    "category": "personal",
    "name": "groceries",
   "description": "Pick up apples and strawberries.",
   "isComplete": false,
  "_rid": "Le4RAMNCjb4BAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self":"dbs/Le4RAA==/colls/Le4RAMNCjb4=/docs/Le4RAMNCjb4BAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00000ab3-0000-0700-0000-636393880000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1667470216
   },
{
"id": "2",
"category": "social",
"name": "activity",
"description": "social activity statu",
"isComplete": false,
"_rid": "Le4RAMNCjb4CAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Le4RAA==/colls/Le4RAMNCjb4=/docs/Le4RAMNCjb4CAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00000bb3-0000-0700-0000-6363943e0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1667470398
   },
{
"id": "3",
"category": "personal",
"name": "rent",
"description": "transfer rent and pick up apples ",
"isComplete": false,
"_rid": "Le4RAMNCjb4DAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Le4RAA==/colls/Le4RAMNCjb4=/docs/Le4RAMNCjb4DAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00000cb3-0000-0700-0000-636394b70000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1667470519
 },
{
  "id": "4",
"category": "professional",
"name": "activity",
"description": "Pot luck activity. Bring apples and snacks",
"isComplete": false,
"_rid": "Le4RAMNCjb4EAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Le4RAA==/colls/Le4RAMNCjb4=/docs/Le4RAMNCjb4EAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"000012b3-0000-0700-0000-636395890000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1667470729
},
 {
"id": "5",
"category": "personal",
"name": "Diet",
"description": "It is suggested to add apples in your diet",
"isComplete": false,
"_rid": "Le4RAMNCjb4FAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Le4RAA==/colls/Le4RAMNCjb4=/docs/Le4RAMNCjb4FAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"000013b3-0000-0700-0000-636395d00000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1667470800
},
{
"id": "6",
"category": "personal",
"name": "Snacks",
"description": "Fruit salad including apples, grapes, banana and mango",
"isComplete": false,
"_rid": "Le4RAMNCjb4GAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Le4RAA==/colls/Le4RAMNCjb4=/docs/Le4RAMNCjb4GAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00001eb3-0000-0700-0000-6363961e0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1667470878
},
{
"id": "7",
"category": "personal",
"name": "groceries",
"description": "bring apples and oats.",
"isComplete": false,
"_rid": "Le4RAMNCjb4HAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Le4RAA==/colls/Le4RAMNCjb4=/docs/Le4RAMNCjb4HAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00002bb3-0000-0700-0000-636399c80000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1667471816
 }
  ]
```

3. The table has column with name description. Total six records in table contains the term apples in description column.
4. Created a search service.
   [image]
5. Selected Azure cosmos DB as data source, created index and created indexer.

Data source

[image]index

[image]indexer

[image]
6. Using Azure search explorer, given a query term as below to get only top 5 records containing term apples.

**$top=5&search='apples'**
[image]
Here is the output of above query,

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://<searchservicename>.search.windows.net/indexes('cosmosdb-index')/$metadata#docs(*)",
"value": [
{
"@search.score": 0.26742277,
"id": "3",
"category": "personal",
"name": "rent",
"description": "transfer rent and pick up apples ",
"isComplete": false,
"rid": "TGU0UkFNTkNqYjREQUFBQUFBQUFBQT090"
  },
{
"@search.score": 0.25811607,
"id": "6",
"category": "personal",
"name": "Snacks",
"description": "Fruit salad including apples, grapes, banana and mango",
"isComplete": false,
"rid": "TGU0UkFNTkNqYjRHQUFBQUFBQUFBQT090"
 },
{
"@search.score": 0.20521776,
"id": "7",
"category": "personal",
"name": "groceries",
"description": "bring apples and oats.",
"isComplete": false,
"rid": "TGU0UkFNTkNqYjRIQUFBQUFBQUFBQT090"
 },
{
"@search.score": 0.2034302,
"id": "1",
"category": "personal",
"name": "groceries",
"description": "Pick up apples and strawberries.",
"isComplete": false,
"rid": "TGU0UkFNTkNqYjRCQUFBQUFBQUFBQT090"
},
{
"@search.score": 0.16281115,
"id": "4",
"category": "professional",
"name": "activity",
"description": "Pot luck activity. Bring apples and snacks",
"isComplete": false,
"rid": "TGU0UkFNTkNqYjRFQUFBQUFBQUFBQT090"
     }
  ]
}
```

**Reference:**  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-portal#add-data-to-your-database